# How to marshall struct from c# to c++?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct, marshalling

I have a task to create marshalling c# structs based on c++ structs (also with inner structs). Then I should to sent this c# structs to dllimport c++ method.

Base c++ structs below:

```
    
    struct WProtims_Task_Table
    {
        Protims_DWN_OS_Task p_List_OS_Task[20];
        Protims_CMD_CFSYS_Task p_List_CFSYS_Task[20];

        int iTotalTaskNum;
    } ;

    struct WProtims_QueryDownloadTask_ACK
    {
        BYTE SystemDateTime[6];
        BYTE TaskTableLen[4];
        BYTE RespCode[1];
        WProtims_Task_Table *p_Total_DWN_Tasks;
    } ;
```

One struct (WProtims_QueryDownloadTask_ACK) contain pointer to array of other struct (WProtims_Task_Table *). I create c# structs below:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    class WProtims_Task_Table
    {      
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public Protims_DWN_OS_Task[] p_List_OS_Task = new Protims_DWN_OS_Task[20];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public Protims_CMD_CFSYS_Task[] p_List_CFSYS_Task = new Protims_CMD_CFSYS_Task[20];

         public int iTotalTaskNum;
    } ;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    class WProtims_QueryDownloadTask_ACK
    {
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
         public byte[] SystemDateTime;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
         public byte[] TaskTableLen;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
         public byte[] RespCode;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
         public WProtims_Task_Table[] p_Total_DWN_Tasks = new WProtims_Task_Table[20];
    } ;
```

When I sent this struct to c++ method, I get properly first fields (byte arrays of  SystemDateTime, TaskTableLen, RespCode), but the last one field (pointer to array of WProtims_Task_Table) contain a garbage. I can not find a way to marshall properly array data to c++ struct?

Comment: One proper way to use IntPtr instead of array of struct (WProtims_Task_Table[] -> IntPtr) in p_Total_DWN_Tasks. And use Marshall.AllocHGlobal to alloc memory. But is it a other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn4) for this. I use it regularly for bringing C++ objects into C# and it's very straight forward.